# Hide old price when group price is setted - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, discount, group

I am using magento version 2.3.1 with the "Porto" theme installed. I have set a group price for a product. In the frontend I see the original strikethrough price and the set price for user group. Is it possible to hide the original strikethrough price **ONLY** when the group price is set? While if I set the "normal" discount (special price) is the original price shown?

Recapping:
If I set a group price -> show only group price
If I set a discount (special price) -> show both (original and special price)

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Yes, we need to add a condition in code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How should I act to do it? and on which files?

Comment: okay first let me know where you need it? I mean which file.

Comment: wherever the price of the product is shown in frontend

Comment: I mean any specific page?